# Clojure can't find library from clojar

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have added the library (green-tags) in my project.clj:

```
(defproject musicdb "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [
        [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
        [claudio "0.1.2"]
        [green-tags "0.3.0-alpha"]  
  ])
```

Then i ran `lein deps` which installed the library in /home/ls/.m2/repository

```
[ls@zilla musicdb]$ sudo find /home -name green-tags -print
/home/ls/.m2/repository/green-tags
/home/ls/.m2/repository/green-tags/green-tags
```

I still get a "filenotfound" error.

```
[ls@zilla musicdb]$ lein test
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate green_tags__init.class or green_tags.clj on classpath: , compiling:(musicdb/filesystem.clj:2:52)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7142)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at musicdb.core_test$eval182$loading__4958__auto____183.invoke(core_test.clj:1)
    at musicdb.core_test$eval182.invoke(core_test.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at user$eval85.invoke(form-init4450700702774542526.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
**Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate green_tags__init.class or** green_tags.clj on classpath: 
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:443)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:628)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5618)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at musicdb.filesystem$eval207.invoke(filesystem.clj:3)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    ... 55 more
```

So i tried setting the classpath variable to the directory where green-tags is installed

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/ls/.m2/repository
```

But it still cannot find the library

This is how i try to import the library in my code

```
(require 'green-tags)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```
(require 'green-tags.core)
```

...or, if you wanted to follow convention, in your ns declaration, something like:

```
(ns your-code-namespace
  :require [green-tags.core :as green-tags])
```

not

```
(require 'green-tags)
```

This is obvious when [looking at the library's source](https://github.com/DanPallas/green-tags/blob/master/src/green_tags/core.clj), or using a tool such as `unzip -l` to look at the contents of the jar.